# MATLAB nested event notifications?

Tags: matlab, event-listener

It seems MATLAB handles will not respond to more than one notification from the same source at a time. Unfortunately this is a big problem for me. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
classdef testClass < handle
    events
        testevent
    end

    methods
        function obj = testClass
            obj.addlistener('testevent', @obj.respond);
        end
        function raise(obj)
            obj.notify('testevent');
        end
        function respond(obj, varargin)
            fprintf('Responded!\n');
            obj.raise();
        end
    end

end
```

when I execute the code

```
c = testClass;
c.raise();
```

The result is

```
Responded!
```

But I really want the recursion to work, though obviously in this simple example it would recurse infinitely. Is there any way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the listener recursive by setting the listener handle's `Recursive` property to `true`. [Listener handle properties are in the event.listener help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/event.listener.html). You just need to specify an output argument to `obj.addlistener` to retrieve the handle.

Here's the code I used to make it work:

```
classdef testClass < handle
    events
        testevent
    end

    methods
        function obj = testClass
            lh = obj.addlistener('testevent', @obj.respond);
            lh.Recursive = true;
        end
        function raise(obj)
            notify(obj,'testevent');
        end
        function respond(obj, varargin)
            fprintf('Responded!\n');
            obj.raise();
        end
    end
end
```

Also note that there is a default recursion limit of 500 calls, so naively the code won't infinitely recur; use `set(0, 'RecursionLimit', N)` to change that. I would think setting `N=inf` is a bad idea.